# Object reference not set to an instance of an object for SqlConnection

Tags: c#, sql, nullreferenceexception

I got this error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   I can't find what is the problem.   Thanks

```
protected void Check_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
                            ConnectionStrings["DbCar"].ConnectionString);
 .....
}

 <connectionStrings>
   <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data  
    Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DbCar.mdf;Integrated 
    Security=True;User 
    Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection string name `ConnectionString` not `DbCar`

```
new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
                        ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of the connectionstring is `ConnectionString` rather than `DbCar`

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
                        ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 1):

`ConnectionStrings["DbCar"]`

You do not have a connection string by that name. You need to rename your connection string from `ConnectionString` to `DbCar` or change the name in the code to `ConnectionString`.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** You are refering to invalid `connectionstring` name. there is no ConnectionString in your configuration file with name `DbCar`.

**Solution :** you need to refer to the valid `ConnectionString` Name from the configuration file.

**Solution 1:** either change the name of `DbCar` to `ConnectionString` from the code.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
                            ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

**Solution 2:**  or change the name of the connectionstring in config file from `ConnectionString` to `DbCar`.

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DbCar" connectionString="Data  
    Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DbCar.mdf;Integrated 
    Security=True;User 
    Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```